# Crash due to MapboxTelemetry (No virtual method initialize)

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Without any change in Mapbox-related classes, I'm having a crash right after running my app.

I have no clue what's causing this, and can't find any response anywhere.

These are my gradle dependencies:

```
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.0-beta.3@aar'){
    transitive=true
}

compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

This is the crash log

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 16817
>                                                                                        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method initialize(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/mapbox/services/android/telemetry/location/LocationEngine;)V in class Lcom/mapbox/services/android/telemetry/MapboxTelemetry; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.MapboxTelemetry' appears in /data/app/com.example.myapp-4RgMqGrrEFZc1X5nPn936g==/base.apk:classes84.dex)
>                                                                                            at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getInstance(Mapbox.java:58)
>                                                                                            at com.example.myapp.App.onCreate(App.java:128)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5791)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>
> 11-02 10:10:35.386 16817-16817/com.example.myapp E/CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task.
>                                                                                         java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>                                                                                             at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
>                                                                                             at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.executeSyncLoggingException(CrashlyticsExecutorServiceWrapper.java:44)
>                                                                                             at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:251)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)
>                                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1953)

Comment: I tried initialising Mapbox in two different ways, with same result: `//        MapboxAccountManager.start(this, getString(R.estring.mapbox_access_token));
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));`

Answer (score 1):

After several hours struggling, I found there was some kind of dependencies conflict. Checking inside Mapbox.getInstance method, there was a LocationEngine parameter passed to MapboxTelemetry.getInstance that was not taken from the right package.

Long story short, these are the gradle dependencies needed to avoid this annoying crash:

```
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.0-beta.3@aar'){
    transitive=true
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-services'
}

compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT') {
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-sdk'
    exclude group: 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk', module: 'mapbox-android-telemetry'
}
```

I hope this helps anybody!